# characteristic of a Zener diode

Tags: diodes, zener

In my note I have when a ideal Zener diode is applied on a reverse voltage \$U_i\$.

If \$|U_i|>|U_z |>0\$ so \$|U_i|=|U_z|\$ for all \$i\$.

If \$|U_z|<|U_i|<0\$ so \$i=0\$ for all \$|U_i|\$.

I don't understand why we use an absolute value when expressing the voltage and why here for the second case the absolute value is negative
Thanks for replying.

Comment: Please capitalize the noun Zener, "a Zener diode". A Zener diode is a diode which can be forward-biased and thus exhibits a classical \$V_f\$ drop as any Si diode would. It is however used in reversed-biased conditions and goes into avalanche or Zener mode depending on the breakdown voltage.

Comment: Punctuation is mandatory in most places.

Comment: Your notes are impossible to understand. I can promise you that no absolute value of any real number will be smaller than 0. Hint: do not take notes, look for a good book and use your time to learn instead of making practices of stenography.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what it means to *"apply a Zener voltage on a reverse voltage"*, so I skipped the equations and the rest of your question.  I'll therefore answer about Zener diodes in general.

Zener diodes are really simple to understand.  When forward biased, they act like a ordinary diode.  That means they conduct with a small voltage drop across them.  For silicon, this is usually in the 600 to 750 mV range, depending on the diode, the current, and the temperature.

The special thing about Zener diodes is what they do when you apply reverse voltage to them.  These diodes are meant to be used in reverse, and will have a specific voltage across them.  In this way, they can be used as independent voltage references.

Ideally a Zener diode doesn't conduct at all until the reverse voltage across it reaches the Zener voltage.  After that it looks like a fixed voltage source and can sink infinite current.

Real Zener diodes have a "knee" region where the current goes up dramatically with a small increase in reverse voltage.  The dynamic resistance at the Zener voltage is something the datasheet tells you.

Since Zener diodes have significant voltage across them during normal use, you have to be careful of their power dissipation.  A 10 V Zener, for example, dissipates 100 mW for every 10 mA through it.